# Remove punctuation from a list using loops-Python3

Tags: loops, punctuation

So what I'm trying to do is create a function that reads in a list and create a new list without the punctuation, using loops.
So far, I've got:

```
list=["This:","is","a","list."]
def depunctuate():
    for i in range(0,len(list),1):
        list1=""
        for j in range(0,len(list[i]),1):
            if(list[i][j] !=['(',')','?',':',';',',','.','!','/','"',"'"]):
                list1+=list1[i][j]
            cleanList+=[list1]
    return cleanList
depunctuate()
```

So what I'm looking for it to return is "This is a list"
However I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "depunctuate.py", line 10, in <module>
    depunctuate()
  File "depunctuate.py", line 7, in depunctuate
    tokens1 += tokens1[i][j]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
clean_l = [s.strip(".:;,'\"?!/") for s in l]
```

This will remove leading and trailing punctuation chars.

Comment: I know it makes it more complicated and is unnecessary, but I'm really supposed to use loops. This for a project in my CS150 class